# Influence on Object Constraint and Visual Transform ruins earlier keyframes

Tags: keyframes, tracking

So I have a camera parented to a null object following a path with the follow path constraint, which works fine.

I want the camera to focus on an object at a given time and then after some time stop focusing on that object. For that purpose i use the Object Constraint Track To, and manipulate it with the influence. This works fine, but the problem occurs when I want to stop focusing on the object and just control the camera with regular keyframes. I remove the influence, and the camera moves to another position than I want, but I fix that using CTRL A → visual transform.

But now, when I got to my earlier keyframe (with the Influence being 0) the transformation of my camera is all wrong.

How can I keep my early keyframes and also do the Visual Transform after I’m done tracking the object?

Thank you

[image]